# The "nam" is not getting updated on clicking the button. It is showing blank space after "Hello" after the click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const App = () => {
    
    const [disp,setDisp] = useState(1);
    let nam;

    function prin() {
        setDisp(nam);
    }            




    return(

        <>
        <h1>Hello  {disp}</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" value={nam}/>
        <button onClick={prin}> Click Me !</button>
        

        </>
    )

};
export default App;
```

There's some problem with the prin() function. I am a beginner trying to learn ReactJS Hooks. Please help me with the bug in the code and the concepts involved here. The goal of the program is to display the name after "Hello" after the button is clicked.

Comment: Why can't you use `disp` and change value using `setDisp` as soon as you change in `input`?

Answer (score 0):

`nam` is `undefined` and it won't change.

All you have to do is create two state and then update the value that you want to show in `h1` using button click as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-taussig-d4xlwo?file=/src/App.js)

```
const App = () => {
  const [disp, setDisp] = useState("");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  function onChangeInput(e) {
    setDisp(e.target.value);
  }

  function prin() {
    setInputValue(disp);
    setDisp("");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {inputValue}</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your Name"
        value={disp}
        onChange={onChangeInput}
      />
      <button onClick={prin}> Click Me !</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you share what mistake have i commited in my code ?